# Get "data-orignalprice" attribute values using prototype

Tags: jquery, magento-1.9, prototypejs

I am working on magento. on select-option I have added data-orignalprice="". There are many options. I need to get value. can you please help me how can I get it. check image.
[image]

Comment: Is this valid HTML? I've never seen data-attributes at this level before, only on the individual tag level.

Comment: yes. I have added custom attribute and this is valid

Answer (score 3):

You can get this attribute using Prototype's `readAttribute()` method. There is a wrinkle to this, however. The element you want to read from is not normally exposed by the form input itself. You will have to construct a long-hand reference to it, starting from the element you are observing (the parent).

```
$('your_element_id').observe('change', function(evt){
  var elm = evt.element();
  var data = elm.options[elm.options.selectedIndex].readAttribute('data-orignalprice');
  console.log(data);
});
```

This will log the `data-orignalprice` (ACK! Spell variables correctly!) value from the currently-selected option.

I'm using Prototype 1.7.x (the latest), and this works here. If you are using a different version and this doesn't work, check the documentation for suggestions, or better, upgrade.